# Build GUI project + cairo

Tags: python, python-3.4, cairo, pycairo, pygi-aio

Python 3.4 wxPython

I need to build a project with all the libraries in one folder so that it can be transferred to other PCs. I don't need an exe file. Created a virtual environment, added all the libraries there. But the project uses PyGI 3.24.1 AIO, this package is installed via the exe installer. With this package is installed cairo. If run a project from a virtual environment, an exception occurs:

```
File "D:\project\designer\svg2image.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cairo
ImportError: No module named 'cairo
```

If run from the main python.exe, everything works.

Can I somehow fix it?

And is it possible to somehow add everything that was installed from PyGI 3.24.1 AIO to the virtual environment libraries, or is it always necessary (on other PCs) to install PyGI 3.24.1 AIO?

Comment: pip install pycairo

Comment: @JagadeshaNH, yes. Thank You. This is fixed. But with PyGI not.

Comment: pip install pygi

Comment: @JagadeshaNH, this module does not want to be installed.